# ios app - setting DB user_version

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using sqlite Db in my ios app. I want to get the user_version of the sqlite DB. I have used the following code for set the user_version. But I could not set the value to the database user_version. whenever I am trying to retrive, it's always it returns the 0 value.

set version

```
const char *tString1 = "PRAGMA user_version = 1;";
int resultCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, tString1, -1, &pStmt, NULL); - It returns successful result
```

get version

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt_version = 0x00;

        const char *tString = "PRAGMA user_version;";

        int resultCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, tString , -1, &stmt_version, NULL);

        if (resultCode == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSDictionary *resultDict;
            while (sqlite3_step(stmt_version) == SQLITE_ROW)
                resultDict = [self resultDictionaryInStatement:stmt_version];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt_version);
```

It returns the successful response. but the value is default value.

Please guide me what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I have to execute the **PRAGMA** queries using **sqlite_exec3**. I had used sqlite3_prepare_v2. sqlite3_prepare_v2 is not correct way to execute that query.

Thanks